# Find the next term of $\frac14,1,\frac94,2+\frac2{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{5}{2} + \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{2}}, 3 + 3 \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} (5 + \sqrt{5})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

You are given the sequence:
$$\frac{1}{4}, 1, \frac{9}{4}, 2 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{5}{2} + \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{2}}, 3 + 3 \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} (5 + \sqrt{5})}$$

What is the next number? Explain

Hint: The next number is rational.

This is my own puzzle

Comment: Could be literally anything without more information.

Comment: I added a hint.

Comment: @ConorJamesThomasWarfordHen: If you already know the answer, you should clearly say so. Generally, Math.SE is for asking questions whose answer you *do not* know; [Puzzling.SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) is available for riddling readers.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that was bad form. I'd seen similar questions with hints given here.

Comment: The next number in the sequence is zero. The pattern is that all the numbers after the first six terms of the sequence are zero.

Comment: @ConorJamesThomasWarfordHen In my experience, these are problems one does not know the answer to with hints given from others (e.g. "I was trying to solve <problem>; the textbook says <hint>"), and not puzzle-type questions.

Comment: @DanielHast Each term is greater than the last

Comment: @ConorJamesThomasWarfordHen: It's okay. Just keep in mind that the Math.SE community primarily exists to *help* people; the operating assumption is that a questioner *needs help*. When that's not the case —be it with puzzles or challenges— it's important to make readers aware of this. Otherwise, they risk wasting time formulating answers, composing clear explanations, perhaps even posting figures or formatting complicated equations. It's no fun to go through all that effort only to be told "Yep. That's the solution I had in mind" or "That's how I did it. I'm looking for another way".

Comment: @ConorJamesThomasWarfordHen Okay, the rest of the sequence is 100, 101, 102, ...

Comment: @DanielHast What is up with the sarcastic remarks? OP asked a question on a sequence he came up with. It is generally hard to find the suitable next-term of such series. This is not the good SE to post it, and calling on that is fine.

Comment: I didn't realize original sequence puzzles were a faux pas around here. I just thought this was an interesting puzzle. I've posted it to Puzzling SE now. If there's a way I could improve it for this SE, like giving the last term and asking for the pattern, or something else, I'm happy to take suggestions but if this just isn't the place for original puzzles I understand.

Comment: I could have given more context or hints, but I've seen questions like this before with very little context get answered quickly, to my amazement. It's very impressive. So I wanted to start with less rather than more.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure, if this is the intended one. But from $9/4$ onwards we can write:
$$\small{\begin{align}& \frac{9}{4}, 2 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{5}{2} + \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{2}}, 3 + 3 \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} (5 + \sqrt{5})}\\ \Rightarrow&\frac{3}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2\left(1\right)}\right),\frac{4}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}\right),\frac{5}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right),\frac{6}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2\left(\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{8}}\right)}\right) \\ \Rightarrow& \frac{3}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right),\frac{4}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right),\frac{5}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right),\frac{6}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)\right)\end{align}}$$

If this is the pattern, then the next term will be:
$$\frac{7}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)=7$$

Which is also rational. I'll update on this later.

Comment: This is indeed the next term I had in mind. Good job.